# Layout : How to make one widget 3x the rest in a vertical layout

Tags: qt, layout, qt-designer

I have 3 tables (A,B and C) in a vertical layout.The size policy (Horizontal and vertical) of these 3 are set to expanding. How can I make table-A  3 times the size of B and C and always have that ratio maintained. I am doing this through QT Designer.

Update:

In order to test the layout stretch method. I added four QlistWidgets inside a vertical layout to a form having a horizontal layout. Here is the XML for the form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>formPracticeClass</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="formPracticeClass">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>847</width>
    <height>661</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>formPractice</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2" stretch="1,0,0,0">
      <item>
       <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget"/>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget_3"/>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget_2"/>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget_4"/>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources>
  <include location="formpractice.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

The vertical layout with the 4 widgets has a stretch layout of 1,0,0,0. The height of the topmost widget looks smaller to the others. I want the topmost widget to be 2 times  bigger than the others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the layout that contains the 3 tables, set the `layoutStretch` property to `3,1,1` in Qt Designer.  This specifies that the first element in the layout should have 3 times the space as the other two elements in the layout.

**Update:**

For your updated example .ui file, you can make the topmost widget to be 2 times larger than the others by setting the `layoutStretch` to `2,1,1,1`:

```
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2" stretch="2,1,1,1">
```

Note that the stretch property specifies *ratios* between the different elements of the layout.  In other words, you won't get the desired results if you set one of the elements in the `layoutStretch` property to `0`.

Comment: but this way the TableA increases and table b and c remain the same size and they dont expand when the form is enlarged

Comment: @Rajeshwar Did you try it? It works just as expected, all tables expand, B and C included.

Comment: yes i did. The layout constraint is  set to the default Layout Constraint. to me it seems like Table is set to expanding while b and C become fixed.

Comment: @Rajeshwar I can't reproduce your results.  Are you setting other properties on the tables or layout?

Comment: I am trying this on another form. Will post the result in a bit just to be sure I might not be altering other properties